# Nuxt and Firebase/FireStore: Can't return data when using asyncData() and onSnapshot()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I am trying to use firebase/firestore with Nuxt asyncData() and for some reason my data is not being returned at all. **No errors in console, either**.

Anyone spot anything?

Here is my code:

> index.vue

```
  async asyncData({ app, error }) {
    const docRef = await app.$fireStore.collection('photos')
    try {
      docRef.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
        const snapData = []
        snapShot.forEach((doc) => {
          snapData.push(doc.data())
        })
        return {
          snapData
        }
      })
    } catch (e) {
      error({
        statusCode: 503,
        message: 'Unable to fetch posts at this time. Please try again.'
      })
    }
  },
```

Here is my devtools screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have gotten it working. I had to write it like so:

```
  async asyncData({ app, error }) {
    const photosArr = []
    const docRef = await app.$fireStore.collection('photos')
    try {
      docRef.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          photosArr.push(doc.data())
        })
      })
      return {
        photos: photosArr
      }
    } catch (e) {
      error({
        statusCode: 503,
        message: 'Unable to fetch posts at this time. Please try again.'
      })
    }
  },
```

Comment: But now there is another issue....it won't display my photos unless i navigate away and back to the page....

Comment: SO i had to separate the asyncData from the client. I called the client side version of this code in the `mounted()` hook.